# How to make a dynamic form from JSON in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a form in angular using json. When I take a single json file it is easy, because I write my html and using iteration I display the form fields. Now if I have 3 or 4 json files I need to generate a different form with different ids and display it. Can I generate dynamic forms?

I take two button which get json data from file "A" and "B". I need to show the different form on click.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OqlTmddgAGRkcXSKtJNT?p=preview)

```
$scope.getFromAFile = function() {
  // body...
  var inputs=[];
  $http.get('a.json')
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.formInputs = data.input;
      angular.forEach($scope.formInputs, function(value, key) {
          /* do something for all key: value pairs */
          inputs.push({
            "value": value.value,
            "inputValues": value.inputValues,
            "type": value.inputType.toLowerCase(),
            "name": value.name,
            "required": value.required
          })
      });
      getFormfromData(inputs,'BID');
    })
    .error(function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
}

$scope.getFromBFile = function() {

// body...
$http.get('b.json')
  .success(function (data) {
    var inputs=[];
    $scope.formInputs = data.input;
    angular.forEach($scope.formInputs, function (value, key) {
        /* do something for all key: value pairs */
        inputs.push({
          "value": value.value,
          "inputValues": value.inputValues,
          "type": value.inputType.toLowerCase(),
          "name": value.name,
          "required": value.required
        });
    });
    getFormfromData(inputs,'BID');
  })
  .error(function (err) {
    alert(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are good "librairies" to build forms from JSON. To name only 2 of them:

- http://formly-js.github.io/angular-formly/#!/
- https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form

Comment: can you share plunker ...using that I didn't know how I will integrate this with angular

Comment: RTFM ;-). Both libraries are built using angular.

Comment: look at this Question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246652/how-to-make-form-in-angular-dynamically

Comment: See this plunker as an example of using formly-angular: http://plnkr.co/edit/dUiO4aWXQoZlyuE6L5iy. Be aware that there is a slight issue with select for which I created a PR https://github.com/nimbly/angular-formly/pull/61 Please accept this answer

Comment: thanks for giving aswer ...i am looking for that but there is problen hoe i will validate form  http://plnkr.co/edit/7IU7WNKjS6NgTus537K5?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313167/how-to-validate-form-using-pristine-and-dirty-in-angular,..there is no proper anwer of validation

Comment: Yet another lib (developed by the company I work at): https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to instead use a library for that, coz why to reinvent the wheel when you already have readymade off shelf components..

Use Alpaca JS : http://www.alpacajs.org/

It allows you creating HTML form using simple JSON structures like this

```
$(function() {
  $("#form1").alpaca({
    "schema": {
      "title": "User Feedback",
      "description": "What do you think about Alpaca?",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Name"
        },
        "ranking": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Ranking",
          "enum": ['excellent', 'not too shabby', 'alpaca built my hotrod']
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And the output for this will be something like

[image: The output will look something like this]

Comment: so can you use in my json ..?I don'y know how I will use in angular.please integrate with angular

Comment: It may so happen that you need to alter your JSON to adhere to the format required by alpaca..

Comment: But I can't change json..I just take vlue from json and make own json then we can create

Comment: In other word I take json value and make own json object .from that object I creat view ?because json file is not my hand it will come in same format

Comment: can we do like that ..? do you have any idea

Comment: Yes, if you are modifying your json in between, than you can do it

Comment: This uses jQuery and not angular!