# why css not apply on form in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[image]

I apply css in form it should apply when my form is invalid .I also write **important** but nothing happen .In other words I make a dynamic form from json ,Now I need to validate that form .so I apply css which is not working.why I am apply css because some one suggest that in this [how to validate form using $pristine and $dirty in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313167/how-to-validate-form-using-pristine-and-dirty-in-angular.can) you please why it is not apply 
here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/ECLvOstUxq5tIDrYicF2?p=preview

```
/* Styles go here */


.ng-invalid {
  border :1px solid red !important;
}
.ng-pristine {
    border :1px solid blue !important;

}
.ng-pristine {
    border :1px solid blue !important;

}
```

Updated plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/ECLvOstUxq5tIDrYicF2?p=preview
I press **login** button nothing happen

Comment: You have invalid style values: `1 px solid red !important` you have a space between the number and `px` which makes it invalid so it does not render that style

Comment: ok sorry checking wait for while

Comment: it create more problem ..it becomes red all field .I need it become red when I  press login button.please check update

Comment: you need to update your CSS to just add the borders to the input fields

Comment: @khakiout I need it show on button click..is there possible to show some text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your css into this

```
input.ng-invalid {
  border :1px solid red !important;
}
```

the class `ng-invalid` applies to the form as well since it AngularJS detects that the form is invalid so it applies the class to the form.

**Edit**

It seem that you are using a third party module for your forms. It has it's own validation styles so we have to use it. Here are some notes:

1. I added the `novalidate` directive to your formly directive. This will prevent the browser to trigger its default validation, the browser's default validation will not trigger the `ng-submit` function if it finds an error.
2. I added an `ng-class="{'form-submitted':submitted}"` to the form directive itself. (This is similar to the approach of [PatrickEvans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320463/3176651)
3. In relation to Item 2, I modified the CSS to this. The red border will be applied if the `form-submitted` class is applied to the parent form.

   ```
   .form-submitted input.ng-invalid {
     border :1px solid red !important;
   }
   ```

### [**See Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r5fJ3CXPA5pUoYssojXj?p=preview)

Comment: but check my update ..It not work.It should become one when I press login button

Comment: I need it show on button click..is there possible to show some text.

Comment: @khakiout thanks for answering but your plunker will not working

Comment: @user944513 please check again :( I must've included a different version

Comment: @khakiout thanks sir you give great solution …do you have any idea to show text ..this "this field is requried" like below the input field example "invalid email" or any text when field is navalid

Comment: it ok….I got the you effort you did great job sir.but please help to solve this issue

Comment: @user2535959 hello, it seems that `formly` does not support messages yet. based on this [thread](https://github.com/nimbly/angular-formly/issues/23)

Comment: do you know any plugin which convert json to form .which this type of validation..secondly is their any way to achieve this using firmly…or other way to achieve this using blur

Comment: @khakiout hello is there any idea

Comment: hello, try looking at this module [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form) and it's [documentation](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md)

Comment: hey I apply your concept please look tho question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321306/why-form-is-not-generated-while-using-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid style values: `1 px solid red !important` you have a space between the number and `px` which makes it invalid so it does not render that style.

If using Chrome, you can look at an elements applied styles and if there is a warning symbol next to the style (and has a line through it) it means it is an invalid value. Not sure what the other browsers Developer Tools looks like for this but this is what Chrome's looks like:

[image]

As for making the css only apply after hitting the login button you will need to setup a check. You can do this by using the [***ng-class***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

css

```
.ng-invalid.apply {
  border :1px solid red !important;
}
```

html

```
<input type="email" ng-class="{apply:loginAttempted}" />
<button type="submit" ng-click="loginAttempted=true" />
```

the ng-class will apply the style `apply` to the element when `loginAttempted` is a truthy value. So when the element gets the `ng-invalid` and the `apply` classes then the border will be rendered.

Comment: I need it become red when I press red .may I use another plugin ?

Comment: it makes what more useless? you haven't done anything except make the style value a valid one, you have not changed it to use the `ng-class`  directive like i mention

Comment: SORRY SIR wait trying .I am trying upper solution see sir I apply this http://plnkr.co/edit/ECLvOstUxq5tIDrYicF2?p=preview.But my form is generated dynamically how I add ng class

Comment: sir do you have ant idea ?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the formly directive? Off the bat i would say you would probably have to modify their code to allow adding in angular directives

Comment: thanks sir ….do you have idea ..I will try but if you know solution please post it

Comment: No i do not, as i do not know anything about that directive and will not as that is a separate issue to your original question. You would need a separate question post to deal with that if you find you are having trouble finding a solution yourself.

Comment: actually I make 2 thread but i did not help by any one see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318214/how-to-use-angular-validator-in-angular-js