# how to generate form dynamically in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-schema-form

I am using this https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form plugin to generate my form will not display .I study all documentation and add all js required i didn't get any error but it not display why ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/FO5iEs6ulmP3aR0PW4nt?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8fq4c4t7jct4w4h/schema-form.js?m="></script>
        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/unk0id7tmc9w0mm/angular-sanitize.js?m="></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/icrciconaesuw29/tv4.js?m="></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rk0dfetihiqs7bi/ObjectPath.js"></script>




  </head>

  <body>
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model"></form>
</div>
<script>
  function FormController($scope) {
  $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, title: "Name", description: "Name or alias" },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj']
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      type: "submit",
      title: "Save"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
}
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks please validate ..just take 3 field one text , number of email

Comment: @khakiout do you get anything ..?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the javascript plugins included were not in a proper order.

Also use `angular.module()` to initialize the controller.

JS:

```
    angular.module('test',['schemaForm']).controller('FormController', function($scope,$http){
   $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, title: "Name", description: "Name or alias" },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj']
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      type: "submit",
      title: "Save"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
})
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7TgQTINyvhXDgHCw2GwH?p=preview)

Comment: Actually I want to make form from json with validation..,may be different from email some other like  "server url " I need to check this using save "button" click or on blur ..

Comment: Found the solution to your problem through the [documentation](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form). Also here the [example](http://textalk.github.io/angular-schema-form/examples/bootstrap-example.html). See if this helps

Comment: thanks karan ..I already found that but I am too confused which plugin is better .this current one one or this one https://github.com/McNull/angular-febworms

Comment: both plugin able to make form using json .confuson only validation on blur as well as on submit button

Comment: or this I just want validation when user press http://plnkr.co/edit/HKHKxmGdAvGkQO6o0qfY?p=preview "save button" .In other word if user press save button if some field required it show error text

Comment: i also had to deal with a similar situation on a project i was working. i went through so many angular directive plugins and later decide to write one my self. but this cough my attention https://github.com/kelp404/angular-form-builder

Comment: can you please give simple example on plunker.I will thankful to you

Comment: @astro please give simple example